# R customizing scatter plot

Tags: plot, customization, scatter

I often find following type of scatter + histograms + correlations plots very useful to understand the nature of my data before getting into the analysis.
Can anyone help me to generate this kind of combined plot in R?

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fAAWb.jpg)

Comment: Aside from base R there are many packages that offer enhanced plot functionality. The `ggplot2` package makes it particularly easy to generate combined plots.

Comment: @ChristophSommer Yes but unfortunately I haven't figured out how to replicate attached type of plot using `ggplot2` yet :X

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care how exactly the plot looks, the `GGally` package offers a ready-made solution for the kind of plot you indicated.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(GGally)

# build a data frame of random values
d <- data.frame(a = rnorm(1000, 10))
d$b = rnorm(1000, 10)
d$c = rnorm(1000, 10)
d$d = d$b + rnorm(1000, sd=.1)

# prepare plot
p <- ggpairs(d, diag=list(continuous='bar'))

# show plot
print(p)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! I'll do some modifications upon yours :D